# MooseX::Declare how can I return an ArrayRef from an attribute default method?

Tags: perl, moose

I realise this is probably a basic misunderstanding of some part of perl or Moose on my part, but I don't seem to be able to return an ArrayRef from a `default` method:

```
has '_directories' => (
    is => 'ro', 
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]', 
    lazy => 1, 
    init_arg => undef, 
    default => method {return File::Spec->splitdir($self->relativeDirectory)});
```

gives:

```
Attribute (_directories) does not pass the type constraint because: 
Validation failed for 'ArrayRef[Str]' with value 3
```

How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`splitdir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec#splitdir) returns list, not arrayref.  You can construct arrayref from list using `[]` constructor:

```
default => method {return [ File::Spec->splitdir($self->relativeDirectory) ] },
```